# How to make a new line in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying this simple receipt code using record and lists and between different customers I want there to be a new line but because its in a list `\n` doesnt work.

I have tried to add `\n` to various parts in the code and tried to add `print("\n")` but that too doesn't work.

```
from collections import *

customer_details = namedtuple("Customer","ID First_Name  Surname Age Gender Product Price")

cus1 = customer_details(16785, "John","Apleased",36,"Male","coffee",70)

customers = [cus1]

cus2 = customer_details(10, "Steve","Jobs",67,"male","tea",40)

customers.append(cus2)

print(customers)
```

When you view the list there should be a gap in between the customers.

Comment: Try `print(*customers, sep='\n')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop

```
>>> for customer in customers:
...     print(customer)
... 
Customer(ID=16785, First_Name='John', Surname='Apleased', Age=36, Gender='Male', Product='coffee', Price=70)
Customer(ID=10, First_Name='Steve', Surname='Jobs', Age=67, Gender='male', Product='tea', Price=40)
```

Or you could use `'\n'.join()` but then you need to convert `customers` from being a list of `namedtuple` to a list of strings first

```
>>> print('\n'.join(str(customer) for customer in customers))
Customer(ID=16785, First_Name='John', Surname='Apleased', Age=36, Gender='Male', Product='coffee', Price=70)
Customer(ID=10, First_Name='Steve', Surname='Jobs', Age=67, Gender='male', Product='tea', Price=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print each element in new line using the join method

```
print("\n".join(customers))
```

Comment: doesn't work because customers is a list of `namedtuple`, not a list of strings, as per his question.

Comment: `print(*customers, sep='\n')` is always equivalent when `'\n'.join` works, but doesn't require the elements to be strings, and doesn't build one big string of everything.